# PowerShell script to Export all the disk and drive details (Including mount point) along with name, freespace and capacity to a CSV file

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get PowerShell script to export all disk, drive and mount point details (including name, freespace and capacity) to a csv file.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content .\servers.txt
Write-Output "disk details"
foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    $a = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $server
    foreach ($drive in $a) {
        $b = $a.Name
        $c = $a.Label
        $d = $a.FreeSpace
        $e = $a.Capacity
    }
    Write-Output "$server, $b, $c, $d, $e " | Out-File C:\EAM\ram.csv  -Append
}
```

The CSV file should be in the below format:

```
Server Name       Disk Name          FreeSpace        Capacity
Server1            Disk1             X GB              Y GB
                   Disk2             A GB              B GB
Server 2          Disk 1             C GB              D GB
                  Disk 5             Z GB              N GB
...               ...                ...               ...
```

Comment: you could try format commands to change output view .See this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-6

Comment: Start with creating objects like: `[PSCustomObjects]@{'Server Name' = ...; ...}` rather than separate variables. There are a lot of examples for this at StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. This will do what you want:

```
$serverlist = Get-Content .\servers.txt
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Computer $serverlist |
    Select-Object __SERVER, Name, Label, FreeSpace, Capacity |
    Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```

If you need particular column titles instead of the regular property names or values in a particular format use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to change that:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Computer $serverlist |
    Select-Object @{n='Server Name';e={$_.__SERVER}}, @{n='Drive';e={$_.Name}},
        @{n='Disk Name';e={$_.Label}},
        @{n='FreeSpace';e={'{0} GB' -f [int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
        @{n='Capacity';e={'{0} GB' -f [int]($_.Capacity/1GB)}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```